# Алгоритм свободного числа

Tags: python, c, алгоритм, числа

День добрый! Как правильно вычисляется свободное число, к примеру есть ряд чисел 1,3,5
как узнать что в этих числах нет чисел 2,4. Мне описание кода не нужно, а нужен сама логика

Comment: А что значит "свободное"? То, которое отсутствует?

Нужны все такие числа или достаточно первого?

Если последовательность отсортирована, то можно использовать модифицированный бинарный поиск:

- A - последовательность чисел от 1 до n

- n - длина последовательности A

- current = [n / 2] - рассматриваемый номер

- если current = A[current] - значит на отрезке 1..current таких чисел нет, рассматриваем отрезок current..n

- и т.д.

Comment: Числа которые отсутствуют

Comment: Ну так я вам начало алгоритма уже привел.

Мы не проверяем подпоследовательность, если ее длина равна (последний_элемент - первый_элемент + 1), иначе - в подпоследовательности содержатся пропущенные числа - их и находим.

Единственное - последовательность должна быть отсортирована и числа в ней не должны повторяться.

Answer (score 3):

Маленькое решение на питоне

```
a = [1,3,5] # исходный список
r = range(min(a), max(a) + 1) # а это список из всех возможных элементов
print list(set(r) - set(a)) # а теперь просто пересечение. `list` добавлено только что бы получить список. его возможно нужно будет отсортировать
ans = sorted(list(set(r) - set(a)))
```

Оно хорошо работает, если в исходном списке есть повторы или он не отсортирован.

Comment: Хе-хе...

>> Q: Подскажите алгоритм сортировки массива

>> A: a = [2, 1, 3];
>> A: a.sort()

Хотя для общего развития будет полезно. Да и свою реализацию по времени будет с чем сравнивать)

Comment: Вы решили, что sorted - это мой алгоритм?

Comment: Почему? Вы же не решили, что a.sort() - это мой алгоритм)

Я сортировку просто для примера привел - просили алгоритм, а не реализацию, скрывающую алгоритм (в моем примере - сортировку)

Т.е., вы предлагаете такой алгоритм:

    1. получаем исходный массив
    2. получаем полный массив
    3. находим разницу в массивах

Но ТС интересовал как раз алгоритм пункта 3, а не его наличие, а Вы простым set(r) - set(a) скрыли этот алгоритм.

Comment: я предложил логику. А как найти разницу двух множеств - это в интернете пруд-пруди.

А вот смысл Вашего первого комментария от меня ускользает. Непонимание `sorted` было единственным объяснением.

Answer (score 1):

перебрать элементы, все кроме последнего, разницу между текущим элементом и следующим взять и положить в массив "свободных чисел"  в таком цикле примерно:

```
for (i=1;i<diff;i++) free.push(cur_val+i);
```

cur_val - текущее значение в перебираемом массиве, diff - массив[n+1]-массив[n];

ну и я предполагаю, что массив на входе отсортирован по возрастанию.

Comment: У меня свободные числа не известны, известные только ряд чисел к примеру [1,3,5] в этом диапазоне нужно найти которые не в диапазоне.

Comment: ну да я и говорю - взять массив известных и перебрать. (только не все которые не в диапазоне, а все которые в диапазоне, иначе свободными числами будет и весь ряд больше последнего значения)
например массив [1,5,6,9];

* 5-1=4, diff=4;в результирующий массив отправляются 3 числа - 2,3,4
* 6-5, diff=0, в р.м. ничего не отправляется
* 9-6, diff=3, в р.м. отправляется 2 числа 7,8
* в конце р.м.=[2,3,4,7,8]

Answer (score 1):

Логика проста. Она уже изложена в ответе [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto).

Если известные числа упорядочены, то они задают границы диапазонов "свободных чисел".

Все что надо сделать, это вывести все числа для каждого диапазона, без его границ.

Собственно, проще написать код, чем досконально объясннять. Код для Си:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void 
print_diapazone (int lb, int ub)
{
  for (int i = lb + 1; i < ub; i++)
    printf("%d ", i);
  puts("");
}

int
main ()
{
  int a[] = {1,3,5,6,9}, n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if (a[i] - a[i-1] > 1)   // диапазон не пуст
      print_diapazone(a[i-1], a[i]);

  return  fflush(stdout) == EOF;
}
```

Вот и все (gcc -std=gnu99 prog.c)

**UPDATE**

Специально для [[[[@BOPOH](/users/5079/bopoh)](/users/5079/bopoh)](/users/5079/bopoh)](/users/5079/bopoh) нашел 64-bit сервер с 6GB RAM и прогнал аналогичный тест для 1 млрд диапазонов.

```
[avp@nas ~]$ cat t.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

volatile size_t last = 0;
size_t ndiap = 0, total = 0;
static inline void udiap (uint32_t lb, uint32_t ub)
{
        ndiap++;
        for (uint32_t i = lb + 1; i < ub; i++) {
                last = i;
                total++;
        }
}

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
        puts("hi");
        size_t n = av[1] ? atoi(av[1]) : 1000000000;

        printf ("n: %ld\n", (long)n);
        uint32_t *a = malloc(n * sizeof(a[0]));
        if (a) {
                printf ("OK a: %p\n", a);
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
                        a[i] = i * 2 + 1;
                a[n-1] = -1;
                printf ("a[0] = %u a[1] = %u a[2] = %u ... a[%ld] = %u a[%ld] = %u\n",
                a[0], a[1], a[2], (long)(n-2), a[n-2], (long)(n-1), a[n-1]);
                for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
                        if (a[i] - a[i-1] > 1)
                                udiap(a[i-1], a[i]);
                printf ("ndiap: %ld  total: %ld last: %ld\n",
                        (long)ndiap, (long)total, (long)last);
        } else {
                perror("malloc");
        }

}

[avp@nas ~]$ gcc -O3 -std=gnu99 t.c
[avp@nas ~]$ time ./a.out 3
hi
n: 3
OK a: 0x1c06010
a[0] = 1 a[1] = 3 a[2] = 4294967295 ... a[1] = 3 a[2] = 4294967295
ndiap: 2  total: 4294967292 last: 4294967294

real    0m4.761s
user    0m4.759s
sys     0m0.001s
[avp@nas ~]$ time ./a.out 
hi
n: 1000000000
OK a: 0x7f0cb6372010
a[0] = 1 a[1] = 3 a[2] = 5 ... a[999999998] = 1999999997 a[999999999] = 4294967295
ndiap: 999999999  total: 3294967295 last: 4294967294

real    0m20.876s
user    0m9.424s
sys     0m3.291s
[avp@nas ~]$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo | tail -1
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz
[avp@nas ~]$
```

Следует отметить, что больше половины времени уходит на *заполнение массива* `a` *границами диапазонов*. Видимо это связано с конкуренцией за память (сервак реально рабочий).

--

Т.к. лимит комментариев исчерпан, могу общаться только обновлениями ответа. Или, [[[[@BOPOH](/users/5079/bopoh)](/users/5079/bopoh)](/users/5079/bopoh)](/users/5079/bopoh), если есть еще вопросы, откройте новую тему.

Comment: Ну так проблема и состоит в том, чтобы найти эти границы.

Ведь элементов может быть больше миллиона/миллиарда/триллиарда - а отсутствующие будут в конце. Я пока до конца дойду - помереть успею двести раз)

Comment: @ВОРОН, если ограничиться типом uint32_t, и реально не печатать (выбросил printf(), просто перебираю эти числа и запоминаю последнее), то на `Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5400  @ 2.70GHz`

получаем:


    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ time ./a.out >/dev/null
    last = -2 (4294967294)
    
    real 0m13.247s
    user 0m12.605s
    sys  0m0.156s
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ 

Или я не понял, что Вас волнует?

Comment: может эти данные поступают не отсортированными и небольшими порциями? А памяти - в обрез. Тогда задача стает интереснее.

Comment: Может быть. Но это вопросы к ТС. 

Из примера его данных следует то, что написали Вы на питоне, словами изложил @eicto и приллюстрировал это же на Си я.

Comment: @avp, ну 200 раз я помирать не собирался, это шутка была, но вот как по мне, так 13с - как-то многовато... Если бы БД с такими задержками возвращала бы данные - толку от нее было бы мало...

Не зря же придумали кучу сортировок, хотя и обычная с задачей справляется не плохо, вот только медленно как-то...

Comment: ничего себе медленно. 330 млн чисел  в секунду.  Одно число на 5 тактов (если я все правильно посчитал). Тут скорее всего упремся в ввод.

Comment: @BOPOH, если речь идет о *всех* "отсутствующих" числах, то каким-то образом придется перебирать (выводить) **все**.

Если о проверке какого-то числа, то надо просто сделать хэш-таблицу из известных или битовый вектор вообще всех (512К для 32-бит чисел) и пометить там "известные".

Если речь о всех "отсутствующих" в диапазоне, который задается проверяемым числом, то предлагаемый Вами двоичный поиск этого диапазона - хорошее решение.

Просто из вопроса не очевидно, что именно хочет @avdoshkin.

Comment: Что конкретно нужно получить алгоритм поиска свободного ip адреса. С начало хотел проверить как будет работать с числами, а потом перенести на ip адреса. Так сказать динамическое выделение ip адреса.

Comment: так это нужно писать с самого  начала! Во первых, вряд ли будет использоваться весь диапазон (2 в 32), а скорее всего небольшой диапазон.
Но там можно применять красивые алгоритмы. К примеру, если подсетка 192.168.*.*, то просто держим массив на 256 элементов типа byte, где храниться кол-во элементов в каждом 192.168.ххх. и минимальный номер группы, в котором есть ещё свободные элементы. Дальше сами догадаетесь.

Comment: @avp, для вывода всех отсутствующих не обязательно перебирать все присутствующие (если все отсортировано, конечно).

И мне интересно - а как вы проверяли? Я на питоне при len(a) = 1000000000 получил MemoryLimit, а при len(a) = 10000000 и 100 отсутствующих случайных элементов результат меньше доли секунды получился (30, если на 10000 умножить)

Comment: Так то питооон... Он же память жрет, как ненормальный. И предназначен для прототипов (или в любом случае для не слишком "массивных" по памяти и вычислениям задач). А в остальном язык очень хороший.

В ответе программа (на Си). Понятно, что printf() работает очень медленно. Я просто заменил его на 

    uint32_t last = 0;
    static inline void 
    print_diapazone (uint32_t lb, uint32_t ub)
    {
       for (uint32_t i = lb + 1; i < ub; i++)
          last = i;
       puts("");
    }

И естественно, последним элементом массива a[] сделал -1, а вывод `last` в `stderr`.

Comment: > Я на питоне при len(a) = 1000000000 получил MemoryLimit

размер элемента то как минимум 4 байта. А это порядка 4 гигов. На 32битной системе точно никто не даст сколько памяти одним куском (и не одним куском также). А на 64 битных я не уверен. 

И дело здесь не в си или питоне. А в банальном ограничении 32 разрядной системы.

Comment: @avp, @KoVadim, так я и спросил - а как тестировали? Надо же было как-то создать массив с миллиардом элементов (или каким-то образом его сэмулировать).

Или 13с не для миллиарда было? Для 10 миллионов я написал свое время - замерял его в питоне - сравнивал время до вызова функции и после вызова. При 1 отсутствующем элементе из 10 миллионов - выполнялось практически мгновенно (умножение на 10000 дало 0).

Если будет отсутствовать каждый второй элемент - тогда самое большое время выполнения должно быть, его не замерял.